# c++ 2D TileMap Render optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, 2d

I have a question about 2D TileMap Optimization.

I rendered the Tilemap but the speed is too slow (Frame-rate == 50)

I think I can specify tiles to be rendered. So instead of rendering all tiles, just render tiles on Screen (Device).

This is my current method.

```js
 //Lower Layer
  for(int y = 0; y < Height; ++y)
  {
   for(int x = 0; x < Width; ++x)
   {
    //if the tile index number is -1, then this is null tile (non drawing) 
    if( Layer1[y][x] != -1)
    {
     // this EPN_CheckCollision() Function is the AABB Collision Function. 
     // if there 2 Rect value's are collide , then return true. 

     if(EPN_CheckCollision( EPN_Rect(EPN_Pos(x*32, y*32)-CharacterPos) , EPN_Rect(0-32,0-32,1024+32,768+32) ) )
     {
     //EPN_Pos structure is consist of (float PosX , float PosY)
     EPN_Pos TilePos = EPN_Pos(x * 32, y * 32)-CharacterPos;

     //EPN_Rect structure is consist of below members
     //float Top X
     //float Top Y
     //float BottomX (not Width)
     //float BottomY (not Height)
     EPN_Rect TileRect = EPN_Rect( Layer1[y][x] % 8 * 32, Layer1[y][x] / 8 * 32, Layer1[y][x] % 8 * 32 + 32, Layer1[y][x] / 8 * 32+32);

       //Blt is Texture render function. 
                     // 2nd Parameter is Render Pos and 3rd parameter is Render Texture's Rect.
     pEPN_TI->Blt("MapTileset",  TilePos, TileRect );
     }
    }
   }
```

This is my TileMapRender Method.

( I use EPN Engine made by directX which is Unknown. So I annotated my code)

I rendered the tilemap that collides with the DeviceScreen ( 1024 * 768 , but for margin)
 because I want to render visible tilemap on screen (I do not render tiles out of device screen).
 So I Check the AABB Collision each tile and (1024, 768) device Screen, now I only render necessary tiles.
 But I think this method has a problem, that it does not render out of screen tiles. 
For statement also repeat all *maptiles;* what a inefficient method...
 Maybe my games frame-rate problem is in this method. So may I ask STACK OVERFLOW how I could do this?

Is there another ways to optimize tilemap rendering?
 Give me some tips please.

P.S

I'm sorry about my knotty question.

Please excuse my English ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be rendering enough tiles to cover the screen, for example if your screen size is `640x480`, and your tile size is `16x16` then:

```
Max tiles on X = (640/16)+2; 
Max tiles on Y = (480/16)+2;
```

Notice how we add 2 for a margin on each side. Next thing we need to do is work out where we are in the tile map, for this we simply divide the camera x position by the tile width.

For example if the camera is at `x=500` and `y=20` then:

```
X tile index = 500/16
Y tile index = 20/16
```

You must also render your tile grid at an offset of `500%16` and `20%16` to account for the "sub tile pixel" scrolling.
For the collision its even easier, you only need to check collision with the tiles the player is on, so:

If the player size is `16x20` pixels and at position `120,200`:

```
X tile index = 120/16
Y tile index = 200/16
Num X tiles to check = 16/16
Num Y tiles to check = 20/16
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: thank you!
i read your tips and i understood it. but i have more question about scroll .

now i can know X , Y tile's index. but i still can't understand about each tile's RenderPos X , Y.

how can i get each tile's Pos X Y when i scrolling smoothly?

Comment: Use the 500%16, this means modulus remainder, this is why you need the +2 buffer tiles

Comment: thanks a lot !! Is there have any recommend system in stackoverflow? i want to recommend your answer the best.